# Visual Web Developer: Operation Not Valid error on Show Table Data operation

Tags: user-interface, webforms, visual-web-developer-2010

I'm using Visual Web Developer 2010 Express to learn ASP.NET Web Forms using the tutorial at W3 Schools.  I'm currently stuck on the database section of the tutorial, located [here](http://w3schools.com/aspnet/aspnet_demo_database.asp).  Under the heading, "Add Database Records", I am told to right-click on the Movie table in the Database Explorer and select the "Show Table Data" option, but when I do, I get the error, "Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object", with no other information.  This error also occurs when I select the "New Query" option from the table's context menu.

I have tried adding the MaxHTTPCollectionKeys attribute to the web.config file as shown [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/319001/Error-Operation-is-not-valid-due-to-the-current-st), in the form of

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="5000" />
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="5000" />
</appSettings>
```

, but it has not helped.  The error has nothing to do with code and is entirely GUI-based, or so I believe.  Any help resolving this error will be welcome.